# Cucumber and associations with a select list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, associations, integration-testing

I'm doing integration testing of record creation with Cucumber.  My feature looks like this:

```
When I go to the create album page      
And I fill in the following:
| Album Title               | Great Album   |
| Record Label              | Decca         |
| Catalog Number            | 778-B127      |
| Number of Discs           | 2             |
| Release Year              | 2002          |
| Internal Catalog Number   | CD 1662       |
And I press "Add Album"     
Then I should see "Great Album was added to the library."
```

The thing is, an `Album` `belongs_to` a `Composer`.  This association is created/selected on the new album page using a drop-down list that is populated with the records of existing `Composers`.  What's the best way to test this association?  I'd prefer to do it in my Cucumber table, but is that not possible?  Do I need to use a factory (or other mechanism) to create this `Composer` and then add something like

```
| Composer                 | Tallis, Thomas|
```

to my table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you could accomplish what you want in a similar fashion

add these steps to your scenario

```
Given composers "Tallis, Thomas" exist
When I go to the create album page
...
And I select "Tallis" from "album_composers"
```

the step

```
Given /^composers "([^\']*)" exist$/ do |composers|
  composers.split(", ").each do |composer|
    Composer.find_or_create_by_name(composer)
    # alternatively, using factory_girl 
    # Factory(:composer, :name => composer)
  end
end
```